# Djangoのmodels.pyでimport errorが起きてしまいます

Tags: python, django, vscode

https://djangogirlsjapan.gitbook.io/workshop_tutorialjp/django_models

こちらのサイトを写経しているとmodels.pyの部分でimport error　が起きてしまうのですがどのようにして解決すればよろしいでしょうか。
解答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: エラーを省略しないようお願いします

Comment: Unable to import 'django.db'、Unable to import 'django.utils'と表示されます

Comment: もしかして、`python manage.py 〜` を実行してエラーになったわけではない?

Comment: はい。vscodeのエラーメッセージでこのように表示されます

Comment: なにかがおかしいと思ったら、そうですか。「vscodeのエラーメッセージ」でもまだ通じません。どういう時に、どこに出るエラーか、追記しましょう。使っているプラグインの情報も必要でしょう。あと素朴な疑問ですが、そのエラーで具体的になにか困っていますか?

Comment: すいません解決しました。ご協力ありがとうございます。